# how to select id from one table and insert into other table

Tags: php, mysql

```
 $select = "SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM `order`";
       mysql_query($select);


   foreach ($_COOKIE['item'] as $key12 => $value) {
        $value22 = explode("__", $value);

        $query1 = "INSERT INTO `cart`(`cart_id`, `product_id`, `order_id`, `Quantity`, `total_price`) VALUES ('',$value22[5],'$select','$value22[3]','$value22[4]')";
        $result2 = mysql_query($query1);
```

The output of this is `SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM order`, so what is the solution of this selection and insertion of the id

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated. Use msyqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

```
$select="SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM `order`";
$row = mysqli_query($con,$select);
if(mysqli_num_rows($row)>0)
{
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($row))
    {
       $order_id = $data['order_id'];
    }
}


  //This way you can fetch data
```

Then use this while inserting value for order_id in your query as in

```
$query1="INSERT INTO `cart`(`cart_id`, `product_id`, `order_id`, `Quantity`, `total_price`) VALUES ('',$value22[5],'$select','$order_id','$value22[4]')";
```

Answer (score 0):

one another way to find last inserted id from the db connection:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO order(a) VALUES('b'));
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

then $id will be last inserted id

Answer (score 0):

### Recommendation:

Use only one batch `INSERT` query. It gives you the opportunity to insert multiple rows at once, e.g. by running only one query. And is a lot faster.

### Used method:

- Extract maximum of `order_id` from `order` and assign to `$maxOrderId`.
- Iterate through cookie items and build corresponding rows
  part of the `INSERT` sql statement. Then add it to the array `$insertRowValues`.
- In the end implode the `$insertRowValues` array into the batch `INSERT` statement.
- Run the batch `INSERT` query - only once.

---

```
<?php

$select = "SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM `order`";
$maxOrderId = mysql_query($select);

$insertRowValues = array();

foreach ($_COOKIE['item'] as $key12 => $value) {
    $value22 = explode("__", $value);

    $insertRowValues[] = "('', " . $value22[5] . ", '" . $maxOrderId . "', '" . $value22[3] . "', '" . $value22[4] . "')";
}

$query1 = "INSERT INTO `cart` 
            (`cart_id`, `product_id`, `order_id`, `Quantity`, `total_price`) 
            VALUES " . implode(', ', $insertRowValues);

$result2 = mysql_query($query1);
```

### Other recommendations:

- Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql`, because `mysql` is already removed as of PHP 5.5.0 (see [MySQL Library - Introduction](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php));
- Use exception handling;
- Use prepared statements to avoid MySQL injection.

P.S: I couldn't test anything.

Good luck!